# Rotating an array by taking size of array and it's elements, direction of rotation, no. of position of rotation from user

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an array and want to take array size, array elements, rotation direction(LEFT OR RIGHT), how many position of rotation user want to do from user. But I'm unable to do so. I wrote but it's not working. Kindly correct my code and help. I am stuck on this problem for so long.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//#define RIGHT 1
//#define LEFT 0
//func declaration
void displayArray(int a[], int n);
void rotateArray(int a[], int n, int direction, int shift_counter);

int main()
{
    int n, shift_counter, direction;
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    int a[n];
    
    printf("Enter array elements: ");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ",&a[i]);   
    }
    printf("Type RIGHT or LEFT\n");
    printf("Enter the direction in which you want to rotate the array: ");
    scanf("%s",&direction);
    printf("\nEnter no of position by which you want to shift: ");
    scanf("%d",&shift_counter);

    printf("\nAfter rotation: ");
    rotateArray(a, n, direction, shift_counter);
    displayArray(a,n);

    return 0;
}
//function for displaying
void displayArray(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);   
    }
}
//function for rotating array
void rotateArray(int a[], int n, int direction, int shift_counter)
{
    int i,temp;
    if(direction==RIGHT) //RIGHT ROTATION
    {
        while(shift_counter)
        {
            temp = a[n-1];
            for(i=n-1; i>=1 ;i--)
            {
                a[i] = a[i-1];
            }
            a[0]=temp;
            shift_counter--;
        }
    }
    else //LEFT ROTATION
    {
        while(shift_counter)
        {
            temp = a[0];
            for(i=0; i<=n-2; i++)
            {
                a[i] = a[i+1];
            }
            a[n-1] = temp;
            shift_counter--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" Is not a problem description. _What_ isn't working? What input did you use, what output did you get, what output did you expect. And so on.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&direction);` That should raise some compiler warning about parameter type mismatch. `%s` expects the address of a buffer to store a string but you provide address of an `int`. If you did not get a warning, raise warning level.  For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: You ask the user to enter a string `"RIGHT"` and then you pass `direction` as an `int` to your function where you compare with some undefined macro `RIGHT`: `if(direction==RIGHT)` How is that supposed to work? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually compiles, together with your input, output and expected output.